# Reading Fixed Width file takes too much time in AWS Glue Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to read a fixed width file using Glue Job in Spark. The file size is 129Mb and it took around 11hrs to write output as parquet in s3 bucket's folder.
It took 6hrs in below method to apply schema to fixed width file and write output as parquet file. Since there are 2types of records in input file we are writing
it in 2 different folders in s3

Operation Performed On Input File:

1. Read File, Apply Schema and Write to s3 bucket's folder as parquet
   I am reading fixed width file as text file first and then applying schema over it. Below is the code to apply schema:

```
sfDict = readSchemaDf.collect()
applySchemaDf = readFileDf.select(*[
                                             substring(
                                              str='value',
                                              pos=int(row['From']),
                                              len=int(row['To'])
                                          ).alias(row['Column']).cast(row["type"])
                                          for row in sfDict
                                      ])
```

schemaDf is a dataframe created by reading json file which contains schema as:
Ex: `{"Column":"number","From":"1","To":"8","type":"string"}`
readFileDf is input file which is being read as text file from a s3 bucket's folder

I would like to know if there's any solution to reduce the time since the size of file isn't too large